# Filter result set in sql based on an external variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

There is a table called Person and has a nullable datetime column "DeadTime" (if it is null, then the person is alive and if it has a datetime value then, the person is dead.

I also have a variable includeDead - 0 or 1 passed from the UI

Is this the only way to achieve this? Using an if-else?

```
if @includeDead = 1
    select * from Person --select all including dead and alive
else
    select * from Person where DeadTime IS NULL --select only alive
```

Requesting suggestions to get the result set in a single select without an if-else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select p.*
from person p
where @includeDead = 1 OR DeadTime IS NULL;
```

That logic can be a little hard to follow, so this is also rendered as:

```
select p.*
from person p
where @includeDead = 1 OR
      (@includeDead <> 0 AND DeadTime IS NULL);
```

Comment: If using this approach, its also worth considering using the OPTION RECOMPILE tag at the end of the command.  This will actually exclude the DeadTime IS NOT NULL from the execution plan, however it will also ignore statistics.  If you care about this sort of thing (and you will eventually) its worth running some test on your data to find the most efficient option.  Keep an eye on the execution plan for the difference between the two, and the time stats for real world figures. Small table I'd expect the difference to be negligable.

Comment: Like the first query, I tried with @includeDead = 0  to find the list of people who are alive ```select p.*
from person p
where @includeDead = 0 OR DeadTime IS NOT NULL;```. But I didn't seem to get the people alive. The result returns all. Please correct me if I'm wrong.